About remove restricted sope from verified app from google cloud console
I am using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive this restricted scope, so per latest information, if we use this may be we have to pay or application verification changes may zero. Currently i have added 1 more https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets scope for my concent screen login and accessing shpreadsheet read,write,so my concern is how to remove this https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive from existing project which is verified and running in customers? and second question is if I removed this restricted scope from verified app then it will hamper my verified application or it will work as it as working now?
I have not try anything much just added new https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets scope. as i do not want to use that restricted https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope.

I Google cloud console for your app You can go to the consent screen -> click edit -> save and continue
then you should come to the screen where the scopes are configured.  Beyond that make sure that you go to the library and remove drive api if you can.
Try this ink

If your app is already verified it shouldn't effect the verification. Your app will continue to work with the current scopes until you complete verification again.
Hope this helps.  Please let me know if you have any more questions. I would be happy to take anything to the team they are trying to improve the process.

so it means after removing my application again go in verification process?
